# php mail not sent

Tags: php, email

This is my code

```
$subject = "Welcome to Last Alliance Standing";
$message = "$name Welcome to Last Alliance Standing, Your account has been registered and you are now able to login and play";
$headers  = "From: Team Laser<noreply@lastalliancestanding.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

if (mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)) {   
    header("location: passwordrequest-success.php");
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Not Sent";    
}
```

The e-mail does not always send, though it does sometimes, sometimes i though get the 'not sent' error

Comment: do you have access to log files or even root access? Also what system are you using?

Comment: i have access to the log files, but not root access as its a shared server with justhost

Comment: What they said was
"I apologize, but we do not provide support for this issue. We provide support for your hosting environment only and we recommend looking at your program's support forums, documentation, or consulting a web developer for further assistance."

I'm running the page now, and its working again, but give it a couple of hours, and it will again stop, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is check does your server support mail function. After that, you can put mail() into try{}catch(){} to catch error code :)

Comment: I've never used try/catch in google, a quick search got me to make this

try {
   
    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo 'No error';
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    throw new Exception( 'Something really gone wrong', 0, $e);
}

but it gets to the no error part, without the message being sent? I am guessing there is a code error, but cant find any real help online

Comment: so, did you check that your server support mail function ?

Comment: yes it does, as it sometimes works, then stops working, then works again

Comment: I don't know exactly what error is. In this case, ask host provider that do they support mail function, and ask them give you sample code to use it.

Answer (score 0):

If your hoster uses a Windows system, changing this line might help

```
$headers  = "From: Team Laser<noreply@lastalliancestanding.com>\r\n";
$headers  = "From: noreply@lastalliancestanding.com\r\n";
```

Also your `$email` should **not** be of the form `Alias <mail@ress.com>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those with tips, i contacted the help desk (for the 4th time today) and eventually got somewhere, as it was a shared account, one of the other accounts was sending a lot of spam, and has now been fixed, though thank you everyone for trying to help